Why is the precision of a floating number lost in js?
I noticed that if the fifteenth number after the dot is 1, then it will be lost.
For example, 13.949999999999991 will become 13.94999999999999 , but 13.949999999999998 will remain the same.
const a = 13.949999999999991;
const b = 13.949999999999998;

console.log(a); //13.94999999999999
console.log(b); //13.949999999999998

Why is this happening?
How can I fix this if number 13.949999999999991 comes from integration?
I've read stack overflow and other resources, but I haven't found an answer.

This is a problem with IEEE floating point math as implemented in most modern computers, and so it is not unique to JavaScript. (edit — well it's not really a problem with the implementation; it's supposed to work that way. It's more like a behavioral characteristic.)

There is extensive material available in the answers to the linked duplicated.
